# MySQLi "CURRENT_MONTH_BEGINNING"... is there a way to get that?

Tags: php, date, mysqli

I am interested in collecting data from the last month in the database with MySQLi.

But using INTERVAL 1 MONTH each month overlaps the other, so is there a way to tell the function to check my current month, start from the first day, and collect all data from said month?

Something like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ip) AS visitor_ip FROM visitor_list
  WHERE visited_date > ( INTERVAL CURRENT_MONTH_BEGINNING)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the current year and month, and 01 as the day:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT ip) AS visitor_ip
FROM visitor_list
WHERE visited_date > CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m'), '01')
```

This has the advantage that any index on `visited_date` will still be used correctly.

Comment: Why the `CONCAT` and not just `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01')`?

Comment: That would be fine as well - I'm used to working on databases that don't have such flexible date formatting, so it didn't immediately spring to mind.

Comment: Well, that was fast, and awesome. I thank you both, i did search, but could not find anything, most likely because i searched with the wrong wording. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate current month starting date from PHP like this:

```
$monthStartDate = date('Y-m').'-01';
```

Then your query will become:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(DISTINCT ip) AS visitor_ip FROM visitor_list WHERE visited_date > DATE_SUB(now(), interval (datediff(now(), '".$monthStartDate."')) day)";
```